# Is $V^TAV$ diagonal in general?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I want to know if the following is a true statement:

> If $A$ is real a symmetric and $V$ is orthogonal then $V^TAV=D$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

To prove it I can say

$$(V^TAV)^T=V^TA^TV = V^TAV.$$
So $V^TAV$ is itself symmetric. So if I know $V^TAV$ is triangular then I'm done. How do I know $V^TAV$ is triangular (if it is)?

Comment: Do you mean $V^TAV = D$ for *all* $V$ or do wish for at least one such $V$ to exist?

Comment: @Eric Towers as the question is written now, there's really very little ambiguity at best

Comment: @user334639 : I see one answer taking one point of view, one answer taking the other point of view, and one answer trying to explain to OP that they seem to have mashed both points of view together.  So I'm not the only reader finding ambiguity here.

Comment: $I$ is also orthogonal. From that   it would be $A=D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably misunderstanding what your textbook or instructor is trying to tell you.

> If $A$ is *any* real square matrix with *all* real eigenvalues, there exists an orthogonal matrix $V$ such that
>   $$
> V^TAV
> $$
>   is triangular.

This is done by induction on the order of $A$; choose an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, and complete a norm $1$ eigenvector to an orthonormal basis; the matrix $V_0$ having these basis vector as columns has the property that $V_0^TAV_0$ has the block form
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & r_1 \\
0 & A_1
\end{bmatrix}
where $r_1$ is some row. By the induction hypothesis, there is an orthogonal matrix $V_1$ such that $V_1^TA_1V_1$ is upper triangular. Note that the matrix $A_1$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$ (except for $\lambda$ having multiplicity one less), so also $A_1$ has all real eigenvalues. Now the orthogonal matrix
$$
V=V_0\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & V_1\end{bmatrix}
$$
has the required property that $V^TAV$ is upper triangular.

If $A$ is symmetric (so its eigenvalues are real), then
$$
V^TAV=V^TA^TV=(V^TAV)^T
$$
is also lower triangular, so it is diagonal.

Hence the theorem is

> If $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, there exists an orthogonal matrix $V$ such that $V^TAV$ is diagonal.

Answer (score 3):

It is false: take $V$ to be the identity and $A$ to be symmetric but not diagonal.

Then $D=V^TAV=A$ so $D$ is not diagonal.

Comment: The identity *is* a diagonal matrix...

Comment: @ Eric Towers Yes, but $V^T AV$ is not!

Comment: This is really the only answer directly answering the question, +1